Best approach to download multiple Word documents from a server in a VSTO Word Add-In: Single HTTP GET per file vs Bulk POST request?
I’m developing a VSTO Add-In for Microsoft Word that interacts with a third-party server to check out (download) Word documents. Here's the workflow:
The server contains a list of Word documents.
I have a Windows Forms application that displays this list in a ListView, allowing users to select multiple files to check out.
For each selected file, the application needs to:
Download the file to the local machine.
Open the file in Word.
Add a set of document variables and save the file programmatically via the Add-In.
Currently, I’m considering two approaches to handle the file downloads:
Approach 1: One HTTP GET Request Per File
Iterate through the selected files and send an individual HTTP GET request for each file.
Process each file as it is downloaded.
Approach 2: Bulk Download with a Single POST Request
Send a single HTTP POST request with the list of selected files.
The server responds with a compressed file (e.g., a ZIP) containing all the selected Word documents.
Extract the files locally and process them.
Please note number of files to be downloaded don't have a minimum or maximum limit defined and it could be one single file or many more files.
Performance: Which approach is generally better in terms of performance for downloading multiple files, especially if the number of selected files is high (e.g., 20–50)?
Implementation Complexity: Are there any notable trade-offs in complexity for handling bulk downloads (e.g., decompressing and validating the files)?
Best Practices: Is there a recommended standard or best practice when building such functionality in enterprise-level applications?
The server exposes REST APIs for file operations.
I am using C# with .NET for the Windows Forms application and the VSTO Add-In.
The downloaded files are Word documents, and I need to ensure each file is fully processed (variables added and saved) before the user begins editing.
Any insights or recommendations for choosing between these approaches would be greatly appreciated!

[so] is a site for specific, focussed questions in software development and program. You are asking about almost every aspect of your system. In any case, some of the answers depend on details in your specific implementation that can only be derived by testing. This is way too broad for this site.
